# Firebase Unity: iOS Push notifications don't work in production mode

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase, notifications, push

I am using the Firebase Unity (BETA) v1.1.1 package. So far everything worked fine, I implemented Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send push notifications from a node server and uploaded the Apple push certificates for development and production (and double-checked that later). Also I made sure to use production provisioning files.

It worked smoothly, but when I uploaded the App to Testflight, Notifications did not make it to the device any more. No matter if I send them from the node server or the firebase console.

I read that on iOS there is a sandbox parameter that has to be set, but I cannot find it in the unity plugin. What could I be doing wrong? I can happily provide more information, I just don't know which you could need.

Comment: Are you sure that you are building with the production provisioning profile? If you are not 100% sure, set it manually instead of letting Xcode automatically choose.

Comment: @turnipinrut thanks, that seems to be the solution! I used the correct push certificates but used the developer provisioning profile for signing the app. I will confirm after I uploaded and testet in Testflight.

Comment: I manually signed it with distribution provisioning profiles, but Notifications still aren't working. @turnipinrut